# How can I create keras functional api of multiple inputs and outputs?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, tf.keras

The network consist of encoder, lstm and decoder.
The encoder take an input image sequence (TimeDistribution) and extract 2 outputs with different shape.
one use for lstm and pass it to decoder and another one use directly for decoder.
The decoder takes two inputs and output one average image with the same shape with input sequence.
How can I write a keras functional api for this structure?

[image]

This is my sample code I have tried:

```
class CustomEncoder(Architecture):
def __init__(self, inputShape=(128, 128, 1), batchSize=None,
             latentSize=1000,  training=None):

     self.training=training
    super().__init__(inputShape, batchSize )

def Build(self):
    inLayer = Input(self.inputShape, self.batchSize)

    net = Conv2D(64, kernelSize=15, strides=4)(inLayer, training=self.training) # 

    net = Conv2D(64, kernelSize=11, strides=2)(net, training=self.training)    
    net = Conv2D(128, kernelSize=7, strides=2)(net, training=self.training) 

    ...

    sample = ...

    return Model(inputs=inLayer, outputs=[sample, net])



class CustomDecoder(Architecture):
def __init__(self, inputShape=(128, 128, 1), batchSize=None, latentSize=1000, training=None):
    self.training=training
    super().__init__(inputShape, batchSize, latentSize)

def Build(self):
    # input layer is from GlobalAveragePooling:
    inLayerA = Input([self.latentSize], self.batchSize)
    inLayerB = Input([8, 8, 64], self.batchSize)

    neta = Reshape((1, 1, self.latentSize))(inLayerA)

    neta = UpSampling2D((self.inputShape[0]//16, self.inputShape[1]//16))(neta)

    neta = DeconvBeta(128, kernelSize=7)(neta, training=self.training) 

    neta = DeconvBeta(64, kernelSize=11)(neta, training=self.training) 

    neta = DeconvBeta(64, kernelSize=15, strides=4)(neta, training=self.training) 

    netb = DeconvBeta(128, kernelSize=7)(inLayerB, training=self.training) 

    netb = DeconvBeta(64, kernelSize=11)(netb, training=self.training) 

    netb = DeconvBeta(64, kernelSize=15, strides=4)(netb, training=self.training) 


    neta = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=15,
                  padding='same', activation="tanh")(neta)
    netb = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=15,
                  padding='same', activation="tanh")(netb)
    net = Average([neta, netb])
    return Model([inLayerA, inLayerB], net)

class ConvLSTMBeta(Architecture):

def __init__(self, inputShape=(None, 8, 8, 64), batchSize=None, latentSize=1000, training=None):

    self.training=training
    super().__init__(inputShape, batchSize, latentSize)

def Build(self):
    # create the input layer for feeding the netowrk
    inLayer = Input(self.inputShape, self.batchSize)
    net = (ConvLSTM2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same",dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))(inLayer) # 1

    return Model(inputs=inLayer, outputs=net)
```

Comment: How does your current attempt look? Have you had a look at https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/?

Comment: "Not all questions benefit from including code." [source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) People seem to forget to read SO's help center. We are here to help, no?

Comment: Sorry something wrong in my post. I have edited my post and put my sample code